# changing Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a (purposely) trivial HTML file with embedded Javascript that outputs an alert every two seconds on the client browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
<script>
    function trivial() {
    setInterval(refresh,2000);
        function refresh() {
            message="hello";
            alert(message);
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
```

What I really want is to change the value of message based on an outside source of data running on the server side.  I'd gladly read it from a file, a socket, a database, anything.  What is the general practice for updating variables in embedded scripts on the server side?

Comment: ajax, or reloading the page, forcing a full-blown client-server roundtrip.

Comment: If I understand on the interval you can call to your server/file/database for what you need and update the variable message to match what it retrieves.

Comment: The most straightforward way to do this is to use ajax, for instance with the help of `jQuery.ajax()`. Lots of "hello world"-type guides about this if you google it.

Comment: Thank you all.  For demo purposes only (I am showing how a web display can replace a legacy Xwindows-based GUI), I will start with having the page reload automatically using a <meta> tag.  I look forward to trying the more advanced solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're communicating with a server, I'd recommend using an AJAX call to a HttpGet controller method:

```
var MessageBody = "";
function trivial() {
setInterval(refresh,2000);
    function refresh() {
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:56259/api/message/GetNextMessage',
            data: send,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (result) { MessageBody = JSON.stringify(result) } }) 

 alert(MessageBody);
        }
```

This means you need to create a Web API endpoint that uses HttpGet and returns the next message to show when called.

Comment: You have placed the alert in the middle of an object literal, so you will get a syntax error. You need to put it inside the success callback function.